# Align tabs always right from the nerdtree file panel

Tags: linux, neovim

I am getting started with neovim. I created a configuration using barbar (for showing the tabs/buffers) and NERDtree as a file browser.

At the moment it looks something like this:

[image: Tabs/Buffer overlapse with NERDTree]

I would like it to look like this, were the tabs and nerdtree do not overlap.

[image: buffer/tabs are placed right from the file navigation]

**Question**: how do I configured NERDTree and/or the barbar plugin so that tabs are always placed right from the NERDTree file navigation. Cannot find the answer on my google searches.